# Not Mapped Symbols

Tags: c, video, buffer

I declared my Video Buffers as follows in a source file:

```
/* Video buffers */
#pragma section ("DecoderBuf0", DM)
static VIDEO_BUF VideoBuf0;
#pragma section ("DecoderBuf1", DM)
static VIDEO_BUF VideoBuf1;
```

while I declared in the header file :

```
typedef struct VIDEO_BUF
{
    uint8_t               Data[VIDEO_BUF_SIZE] ;
    bool                  bIsEmpty ;
    struct VIDEO_BUF      *pNext;
} VIDEO_BUF;
```

I keep having a problem of compilation when I am compiling my program... It says : 
The following Symbols are referenced, but not mapped

What does it mean exactly?

Comment: What symbols? Which compiler?

Comment: Did you include the *.h on your source file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error. Refer to your toolchain docs on how to solve this. In particular, the section titled Linker Symbol Resolution should make the causes of the problem clearer. Your linker file must be set up wrong.